# Can you identify these curved grey parts?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

Any ideas which set they belong to?

[image][image][image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bigger part looks like [47846 - Cockpit 10 x 4 x 2 Curved](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=47846&name=Cockpit%2010%20x%204%20x%202%20Curved&category=[Cockpit]#T=C), which has been in 7 sets, but only in one in light bluish gray, that set ([8096](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8096-1#T=I)) only contains the two wedges that are quite common, they have part number 41749 and 41750.

Comment: Cool, i now figured i have LEGO set 8096 in my mixed box